# Unpredictable behaviour of %f specifier in c

Tags: c++, c

With following code:

```
float f = 23.456;
printf("%f", f);
```

Output for different values of `f` are:

```
 Value       Output
---------    --------       
f = 23.456   23.455999 
f = 23.956   23.955999
f = 23.947   23.947001
f = 23.656   23.656000
```

Why is the value obtained unpredictable or there is a pattern?

Comment: `23.456` is not float, it is a double use `float f=23.456f`

Comment: The compiler most likely warns about that, too, unless you deliberately compile with no warnings.

Comment: Can you check the third one in the list? All of the others I would totally expect, but the third one looks wrong. If my CRT printed the third one, I would report it as a bug.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan: That's not the cause of OP's issue.

Comment: yes bydefault decimal is double.but still why is printf displaying different values for different cases.could you explain in a bit detail please.thx

Comment: I ran the third one on my machine, the output is:  23.947001

Comment: @R.. correct, I misunderstood ..I think stefan's link is helpful

Comment: @YuHao - that's what I'd expect it to print too. If the OPs machine disagrees, there is something else wrong.

Comment: yes.sorry for that i have edited that..but why 001 is at the end?

Comment: this has been asked thousand times on stackoverflow. That's because decimals cannot be represented exactly by binary floating point

Comment: yes.but i wanted to know if there is some order in this which i now know can't be.thx.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is because of [**IEEE 754 32-bit floating point format**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point) which is used by C to store floating point numbers. The Mantissa you have is converted in binary and stored in lower 23 bits of 4-byte space required by `float` variable. Sometimes it is completely convertible to exact binary, at other times it may not be exactly converted so a truncated form of the number is stored, which is when read from memory, evaluates to a slightly different value.

This behaviour is similar as in mathemetics you use value of `1/3` as 0.33 or 0.333 depending on your requirement of precision.

Try using:
`f = 0.25;` or,
`f = -15.625;` or, any decimal value exactly convertible to binary, you will get correct result.

Comment: yes.  numbers which have more than 23 bits of binary representation will give errors? is it so?so the output should depend on how close the

Comment: no. gets to the actual number.But in any case the number will be smaller so why do we get larger value in printf?

Comment: @user2653718 when conversion is not exact, the **closer** "23 bits of binary representation" will be used, sometimes higher, sometime lower.

Comment: here rounding off probably means Missing some bits from the binary representation of the number,is it?

Comment: @chux thx.checking closer no. would may be involve changing the last bit or some other way ?

Comment: @user2653718 The compiler does that for you as in `float f = 23.456`. GTG

Answer (score 8):

This falls into the category of things every programmer should know about floating point. The way that floating point works means that some numbers are not fully representable in floating point. The simplest way to explain this is to ask you to write down the value 1/3 as a decimal number. You start out quite happily, but eventually you end up running out of paper. The reason for this is that in base ten notation, the number 1/3 is infinitely long and so in a sensible encoding system which uses base ten notation to store the number, there is a limit to how long it can be.

Floating point does the same thing, but uses base 2. This means that numbers which seem really simple to us, e.g. 1/10 or 0.1, become infinitely recursive. This causes a roundoff error when you come to print the numbers, simply because the number you stored is not the number you gave to the compiler because it wasn't possible to store the number.

The canonical paper on this is http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html, which is a hefty read, but explains all of this and a lot more.

Comment: Floating point _often_ uses base 2.  Had OP used a FP that was base 10, certainly not common, there would have been no question.  IEEE 754-2008 specifies various decimal FP formats and suspect we'll see more of that in the future.

Comment: @chux - You're quite right that base 10 floats would solve this question, but that would just introduce the further question "float f = 1.f / 3.f; printf("%f", f);" get the answer wrong. There will always be numbers which cannot be precisely represented by a computer.

Answer (score 2):

With `float` or `double` you have a certain amount of bits to represent your number `x` in the computer. For `float` it's usually 32 bits and `double` has 64 bits.

The result of that? You can only store 2^32 different numbers in a `float` and 2^64 in a `double`. Since there is an infinite amount of "other" numbers, it means that these cannot be represented. But people still want to *use* these numbers (a compiler error about the unuseability of a number would be odd, wouldn't it?). Therefore, a number *close* to `x` is chosen. In most applications, this is a "close enough". But for the same reason: Never trust a `float`, i.e. never try to ask "is x = 5?".

Comment: i am missing something here: In the binary representation of floating point the no. stored (assume positive) will always be less than or equal to the actual number.so the round off that will be done will be smaller than the actual number.So why do we get larger values from printf?

Comment: @user2653718 Numbers won't always be rounded down. Afaik, the nearest representable number is chosen which often is slightly larger.

Comment: thx.the nearest representable 23 bit number may be obtained by changing last bit or 1-2 bits or some other way?

Comment: @user2653718: There's always one 23 number below the actual value and one above. These generally differ by 1 bit, but at some places the exponent changes and then the meaning of the last bit changes (by a factor of 2). Regardless, between the two the closest approximation is chosen.